# How to upgrade sphinx in ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sphinx

I am using `Ubuntu 12.0.4`. I need to install `Sphinx version 2+` but in ubuntu, current Sphinx 0.9.9 version.

I want to `remove` it and `install Sphinx 2+` version or `Upgrade from 0.9.9 TO 2+`

But i can not remove or upgrade Sphinx version. Any one have a idea or solution.

I tried but not success and not get a proper solution any where.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not about programming. You might want to re-ask at SuperUser or AskUbuntu.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks I will ask